# Exporting a native method taking callbacks inside a map in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm implementing a [native module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content) for iOS and I want to pass a variable number of callbacks to one of the exported functions to be used as such:

```
nativeModule.myMethod({
  title: "my title",
  onForward: () => { alert("forward"); },
  onBack: () => { alert("back"); },
  onPress: () => { alert("press"); },
  side: "left"
});
```

Because all the arguments are optional, I prefer to pass them as a map so my native exported function looks like:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(myMethod:(NSDictionary*)params)
```

I expected to find in the `params` map the callbacks as `RCTResponseSenderBlock` types. But when I execute the code above I'm only seeing the `title` and `side` parameters in the map. So strings do pass through ok but callbacks are removed.

I think I'm doing something wrong. I expected this to work because of the NavigatorIOS example [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html#examples). Look at how `push` is taking multiple callbacks in a map.

Comment: Do you have find a solution finally?